# Problems running eclipse juno 64 bit on Mac Lion

Tags: eclipse, macos, osx-lion

Sorry for my stupid question, but I just don't get eclipse juno running...

Here the error report:

> Process:         eclipse [10355] Path:
>   /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse Identifier:
>   eclipse Version:         ??? (???) Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:  bash [10309]
>
> Date/Time:       2012-09-10 23:11:26.871 +0100 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.7.4 (11E53) Report Version:  9
>
> Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000003c
>
> VM Regions Near 0x3c:
>   --> 
>       __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100004000 [   16K] r-x/rwx SM=COW 
>   /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
>
> Application Specific Information: objc[10355]: garbage collection is
>   OFF
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8d0f7aef
>   CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName + 31 1   eclipse
>     0x00000001000030bd findSymbol + 66 2   eclipse
>     0x00000001000018be original_main + 1572 3   eclipse
>     0x0000000100001f7d main + 1230 4   eclipse
>     0x0000000100001158 start + 52
>
> Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8fd6e7e6 kevent + 10 1
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff8f90d78a _dispatch_mgr_invoke
>   + 923 2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8f90c31a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
>   0xe1bfa23753d57bd3  rbx: 0x0000000100200ad0  rcx: 0x0000000000000000 
>   rdx: 0x0000000000000000   rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi:
>   0x0000000100200ad0  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbff9b0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbff590
>   r8: 0x000000000000000f   r9: 0x000000000000000a  r10:
>   0x0000000000064000  r11: 0x00007fff8d0f7ad0   r12: 0x00000001000043f8 
>   r13: 0x00000001002007f0  r14: 0x00007fff5fbffbc8  r15:
>   0x00007fff5fbffbc8   rip: 0x00007fff8d0f7aef  rfl: 0x0000000000010206 
>   cr2: 0x000000000000003c Logical CPU: 1

Part removed ...

> External Modification Summary:   Calls made by other processes
>   targeting this process:
>       task_for_pid: 1
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by this process:
>       task_for_pid: 0
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by all processes on this machine:
>       task_for_pid: 16727
>       thread_create: 7
>       thread_set_state: 10414
>
> VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=140.5M
>   resident=68.1M(49%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=72.3M(51%) Writable
>   regions: Total=29.1M written=424K(1%) resident=644K(2%)
>   swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=28.5M(98%)   REGION TYPE
>   VIRTUAL
>   ===========                      ======= MALLOC                             20.3M MALLOC guard page                    32K STACK GUARD                        56.0M Stack                              8712K VM_ALLOCATE                          32K
>   __CI_BITMAP                          80K
>   __DATA                             12.1M
>   __IMAGE                             528K
>   __LINKEDIT                         47.8M
>   __TEXT                             92.7M
>   __UNICODE                           544K shared memory                       308K
>   ===========                      ======= TOTAL                             238.9M

It would be great if anybody could help me.

Thank you very much for your help.

Greetings

Anselm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

found the problem... I used Unarchiver to unpack the pack... It seems to have a bug... When I used another program to unpack it it worked :-)

here the eclipse link as reference: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=305758

Comment: Thanks a lot. Downloaded 2 64bit Versions of Eclipse and both didn't work until I used a different Unpacker. :)

Comment: Hi, What is "another program" do you use? I use `tar -xf eclipse.xxx.tar`, it still doesn't work :(